# Wix: If Define variable contain special character then Bad conditional string error

Tags: wix

When define variable contain special character like @, - etc. and now this variable use in comparison condition then give "Bad conditional string" error. and this condition used in Publish new dialog in custom dialog.

sample code:

```xml
<?define Key="test@key"?>

<Control Id="LicenseKey" Type="Edit" Password="yes" X="20" Y="139" Width="320" Height="15" Property="Keytext" />

<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next">
     <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CheckKey" Order="2"><![CDATA[Keytext <> $(var.Key)]]></Publish>
</Control>
```

so can any one tell me how to solved this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the value of the `var.Key` you pass contains some special characters. I suppose you should enclose the `$(var.Key)` with quotes for this to be assumed a value, like this:

```
<Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CheckKey" Order="2"><![CDATA[Keytext <> "$(var.Key)"]]></Publish>
```